# Need a query for subtraction and division?

Tags: mysql, sql, advantage-database-server

In my table column are like these

msd_mon, msd_yea, msd_sva ... I want a query

```
SELECT
         (((        SELECT SUM(msd_sva)
        FROM  msdfc00 
        WHERE    msd_yea  IN
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT msd_yea
            FROM  msdfc00 
            )
)-(     SELECT SUM(msd_sva)
        FROM  msdfc00 
        WHERE    msd_yea  = '2016'
)* 100) / (     SELECT SUM(msd_sva)
        FROM  msdfc00 
        WHERE    msd_yea  = '2016'
)) AS thePerc,
         msd_yea
FROM  msdfc00 
WHERE    msd_fco  = 'KF'
 AND    msd_mon  = '11'
GROUP BY  msd_yea
```

that is I want to substract sum of msd_sva for period of msd_mon for the year 2017 from  sum of msd_sva for period of msd_mon for the year 2016 . My Base year is 2016. I got only 4 years that is upto 2018. so calulation will be like these

> for year 2016 value will be 0 for year 2017 it will be ((2017 - 2016)*
>   100 \2016) for year 2017 it will be ((2018 - 2016)* 100 \2016) for
>   year 2017 it will be ((2019 - 2016)* 100 \2016)

any help ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when msd_yea = 2016 then msc_sva end) as sva_2016,
       sum(case when msd_yea = 2017 then msc_sva end) as sva_2017,
       sum(case when msd_yea = 2018 then msc_sva end) as sva_2018,
       sum(case when msd_yea = 2019 then msc_sva end) as sva_2019       
from msdfc00 
where msd_fco  = 'KF' and msd_mon  = '11';
```

You can use a subquery to do your final calculations:

```
select 0 as val_2016,
       (sva_2017 - sva_2016) * 100 / sva_2016 as val_2017,
       . . .
from (select sum(case when msd_yea = 2016 then msc_sva end) as sva_2016,
             sum(case when msd_yea = 2017 then msc_sva end) as sva_2017,
             sum(case when msd_yea = 2018 then msc_sva end) as sva_2018,
             sum(case when msd_yea = 2019 then msc_sva end) as sva_2019       
      from msdfc00 
      where msd_fco  = 'KF' and msd_mon  = '11'
     ) m;
```

Comment: select 0 as val_2016,
       (sva_2017 - sva_2016) * 100 / sva_2016 as val_2017,
       (sva_2018 - sva_2016) * 100 / sva_2016 as val_2018,
       ..
from (select sum(case when msd_yea = 2016 then msd_sva end) as sva_2016,
             sum(case when msd_yea = 2017 then msd_sva end) as sva_2017,
             sum(case when msd_yea = 2018 then msd_sva end) as sva_2018,
             sum(case when msd_yea = 2019 then msd_sva end) as sva_2019       
      from msdfc00 
      where msd_fco  = 'KF' and msd_mon  = '11'
     ) m; invalid column sva_2017

Comment: thank you @Gordon Linoff .. I get an error  says invalid column ..

Comment: @Gopipuli . . . The columns names are taken from your question, although there might be typos.

Comment: thanks Gordon Linoff I just split up the query to two tabels, it give me the result. I am not an expert in query. Thank you for the valuable time. If time permit I want one more help nowthe above results are getting as rows Will it get in column wise ? that is under year column ?

Comment: @Gopipuli . . . I don't fully understand what you are asking in the comment.  Can you ask another question, with sample data and desired results to be sure that the explanation is clear?